# Kraken Exchange AddOrder API call

Tags: api

I'm writing a small java app that will allow me to trade on Kraken without using their web front-end.

I have most of the calls working, but can't seem to get `AddOrder` working..
No matter what I send, Kraken replies with `EGeneral:Invalid arguments`

I'm able to do an `AccountBalance` call which is also a private call that needs my API-key and API-Sign. So I'm pretty sure I'm creating the API-Sign properly.

For a simple market order to buy 12 ETH in USD, I would send:

`https://api.kraken.com/0/private/AddOrder?pair=XETHZUSD&type=buy&ordertype=market&volume=12.00000`

Has anyone used this API? Can point out something I might be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: I did. Are you having the same problem?

Comment: yes can you post your solution please?